# Malformed Framework – Archiving app with Facebook SDK misses symlinks

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0

My iOS/Catalyst app has Facebook SDK included:

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

It was working this way for ever, but since a few weeks when I archive the app with Xcode then upload the archive to App Store Connect, I get an email saying:

```
ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBAEMKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'FBAEMKit' -> 'Versions/Current/FBAEMKit'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBAEMKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90292: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBAEMKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Resolved link target: '${linkTarget}'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'FBSDKCoreKit' -> 'Versions/Current/FBSDKCoreKit'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90292: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Resolved link target: '${linkTarget}'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' -> 'Versions/Current/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90292: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Resolved link target: '${linkTarget}'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKLoginKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'FBSDKLoginKit' -> 'Versions/Current/FBSDKLoginKit'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90291: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKLoginKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

ITMS-90292: Malformed Framework - The framework bundle FBSDKLoginKit (MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Resolved link target: '${linkTarget}'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.
```

When I look into the app container which opens when I run the app, it certainly doesn't have those links. How can I fix the build process to have it correctly linked?

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe not the best solution but i end up linking FBSDK with Swift package manager and it works and errors are gone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).